# performSelectorInBackground leading to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Ok, I've got what seems like a very simple situation, but can't figure it out.

In my viewDidLoad, I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WestiesModel *model = [WestiesModel new];
    [model FetchServerData];
} // I know, I'll move the model creation out of the view controller later
```

My WestiesModel.h is

```
 @interface WestiesModel : NSObject
 {
   NSURL *ServerURL;
   NSMutableArray *Westies; 
 }
 @property (retain) NSURL *ServerURL;
 -(void) FetchServerData;
 @end
```

In WestiesModel.m, I have

```
-(void)FetchServerData
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundFetchServerData) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)backgroundFetchServerData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",Westies,[self retainCount]);
    [Westies addObject:@"test"];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",Westies,[self retainCount]);
    [Westies addObject:@"test"];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",Westies,[self retainCount]);
    [Westies addObject:@"test"];

    NSLog(@"%@ %d",Westies,[self retainCount]);
    [Westies addObject:@"test"];

    .
    .
    .

    [pool release];
}
```

I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS at random points in the backgroundFetchServerData function. Its like the model object is going away, but I just leak it in my viewDidLoad function. I don't transition off this screen or anything. I'm on the iOS5 beta, running on the simulator.

Any ideas here?

Comment: What does your init method do? Can you post that?

Comment: in my init, I did do an allocation of the Westies NSMutableArray. I know thats working because when I step through backgroundFetchServerData, I can see elements being added to the Westies array. I just think somehow the WestiesModel object is being deleted. I know there is something new in iOS5 with automatic reference counting - could there be some kind of bug thats causing this to get dealloced somehow?

Comment: may be your are loosing reference to your model object, try to retain it as below and test it again: WestiesModel *model = [[WestiesModel new] retain];

Comment: Tried that, no change. Even tried moving it out of the .m and putting WestiesModel declaration into the .h file, same result.

Comment: Looks like your Westies isn't retained... but hard to tell without code

Comment: Thanks for that comment Eiko and Kal. It motivated me to look again at the allocation of Westies and saw that I was doing an allocWithCapacity but not doing a retain on it, so it was indeed going into the non backgrounded thread's autorelease pool and getting killed off. Sometimes you gotta learn these lessons the hard way for them to sink in. Ok, thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS at random points in the
>   backgroundFetchServerData function. Its like the model object is going
>   away, but I just leak it in my viewDidLoad function. I don't
>   transition off this screen or anything. I'm on the iOS5 beta, running
>   on the simulator.

iOS5 beta is under NDA;  can't discuss specifics of that here.  But, no need.

If you have crashes at random points when doing something concurrently it is because you aren't doing the concurrency correctly, almost always.

In this case, you probably haven't retained all of the objects that are to be used in the thread (prior to spawning the thread) and the main thread's autorelease pool has been drained, causing crashes at seemingly random points in time.

Without seeing more code, impossible to say.   However, a couple of additional points:

- don't call **retainCount** as it is useless.
- methods should start with lowercase letters
- if by "model" you mean "Core Data model", then you need to read the Core Data concurrency guide because randomly spinning off threads will not work.  Doesn't look like you are using CD, so no worries on that part.
- instance variables should start with lowercase letter

This looks like a threading issue or a memory management issue (or both).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the model is not a CoreData model, its just a class derived from NSObject which represents the model for this view controller. Hacked code to try to simplify this, so methods and var case shouldn't matter her.e Calling retain count was showing me that it wasn't a low number, so even if it got autoreleased, it should not have been deallocd. I even defined a release and dealloc stub for the class and put a break point on them to see if they were getting called, and they are not. Seems like some kind of memory corruption, but I started with a blank template.

Comment: ok, found the fix (see comments in question) Thanks for your time to try to address it though.